# how to show or hide tab-content according to the form-wizard condition, vue-form-wizard?

Tags: vue.js, formwizard

I am using the following library:
https://binarcode.github.io/vue-form-wizard/#/

What I basically have to do is show or hide a tab-content according to the marking of a radio button, for that I am trying this way:

```
<tab-content v-if="form.company_referal == 'Yes'" title="Referal Form" icon="el-icon-info">
                <referralForm :form="form.referal_form" :errors="errors" :isDisabled="isDisabled" ref="referralForm"></referralForm>
</tab-content>
```

`form.company_referal == 'yes'` to be able to display it, this `company_referal` property is used in a radio button with the values ​​'Yes' or 'No'

But I have the problem that it adds it to the end of all the tab content when in the radio button of company_referal it is 'Yes', but in reality it should go along with 'SnapShot'.
[image]

If `form.company_referal` is defined from `created` or `mounted` as 'Yes', it does appear alongside SnapShot, the problem is when making the change with the radio button.

This should look like this, even using the radio button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to use a watch property & setTimeout. the setTimeout is important otherwise referral form will always appear at the end (which is the wrong order).

@TabContent

```
<TabContent v-if="form.company_referal == 'Yes'" title="Accounting">
<TabContent v-if="renderQuote" title="Quote"">
<TabContent v-if="renderBindConfirmation" title="Bind Confirmation">
```

@data

```
data() {
  renderQuote: true,
  renderBindConfirmation: true,
},
watch: {
    'form.company_referal': async function(newVal, old) {
      this.renderQuote = false
      this.renderBindConfirmation= false

      // fake delay before code execution
      await new Promise((resolve)=>setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
      }, 0));

      this.renderQuote = true
      this.renderBindConfirmation = true
    },
    deep: true
  },
```

Comment: but sometimes the tabs not order by above to bottom from code if we use v-if .